# How to set category in WordPress new posts

Tags: php, wordpress, html

Uhmm, I want some function. Can you hear me the function description?

**In WordPress theme, I want some function. When somebody adds a post wit the "Add new posts" function, I want default category.**

I already made a DB Field. `wp_user_cat` is the primary key and link `wp_user_cat` in `wp_user table`.

The modified database conditions:
[image: It is the modified database conditions.]

So, I made register-function which added Users' job. I modified `wp_login.php`,  `wp_create_user()` and `wp_insert_user()` function in `users.php`.
It is successful, but I have no idea that set default category in Add new posts function.

**If user-job is Music-Company when user clicks "Add New Posts-Button", it should automatically set the Music-Company Category ..**

This is the "Add new" screen:
[image: It is the Add new Screen]
This theme is MusicPlay theme in aivahtheme.

Please give me help.. I need to know the file names. I can do it! (If possible, give me description.)

Comment: Ok, I got it! Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to restrict posting from `user types` to post only in certain categories, right? So, user of type A, can only post on category A and so on.

You can first create roles for users:

```
function custom_roles() {
    global $wp_roles;
    add_role(
        'user_type_one',
        __('User Type 1'),
        array(
            'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
            'edit_posts'   => false,
            'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
        )
    );
    add_role(
        'user_type_two',
        __('User Type 2'),
        array(
            'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
            'edit_posts'   => false,
            'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
        )
    );
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'custom_roles');
```

And then you use a plugin to restrict those user types to categories:
`https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-categories/`

Note: I haven't used this in a long time, but it should work or at least set you on the right track.

Comment: Right! I want to tell it summary.. Peixotorms is genius!

Comment: Hi, peixotorms ! I have any question!  What do i attach to that file?